# express basic auth challenge argument not forcing popup on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger-ui

i am trying to lock up my swagger documentation, i am using express basic auth for this, when i try to access the documentation endpoint it just throws a `HTTP ERROR 401` without asking me to provide a username and password.

```
app.use("/api-docs",basicAuth({
    challenge: true,
    users: { 'me': 'openforme' }  }),
   swaggerUi.serve,
   swaggerUi.setup(yaml.parse(swaggerfile))
);
```

when i remove the basicauth middleware i can access the endpoint, what i want is a popup to into the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

use the [Nub-auth package](https://github.com/Allaye/nub-auth)

```
const express = require('express');
const nubAuth = require('nub-auth');
app = express();

app.use(['/v1'], nubAuth({
    challenge: true,
    users: { 'admins': 'admin', 'users': 'user', 'guest': 'guested' }
}));


app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World welcome to API endpoints free !');
});

app.get("/v1", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World welcome to API endpoints closed !");
});
```

from my investigation edge does not have the basic auth feature enabled.